# What is the purpose of this test case here?

Tags: triggers, salesforce

Could someone explain what this code is doing to me? I don't understand the purpose of the `system.debug` lines.

```
Test.startTest();
// 1. First check to see if it's a brand new Owner ID
System.debug('first test'); // Creating a new opportunity to start Trigger
Opportunity newtestOpp1 = TestUtil.initOpportunity(TestUtil.initAccount(),TestUtil.initContact());
User testUser1 = TestUtil.initUser(); 
newtestOpp1.OwnerId = testUser1.Id;//setting OwnerId
System.debug('The opp owner should be null' + newtestOpp1.Op_Owner__c);
try{        
    insert newtestOpp1;
} catch ( DMLException d ) {
    System.debug(d);
}
System.debug('The opp owner should not be null' + newtestOpp1.Op_Owner__c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it's supposed to be testing whether some kind of workflow or trigger is setting a value in the `Op_Owner__c` field upon inserting an Opportunity record. The debug statements should actually be `System.assert` or `System.assertEquals` calls though, if the test is meant to actually verify the application's functionality. Debug statements aren't typically viewed during test case execution.

Here's a cleaned-up version that actually makes assertions about the `Op_Owner__c` field's value (which is the purpose of a test case), rather than just printing something to the debug log.

```
Test.startTest();
Opportunity newtestOpp1 = TestUtil.initOpportunity(TestUtil.initAccount(),TestUtil.initContact());
User testUser1 = TestUtil.initUser(); 
newtestOpp1.OwnerId = testUser1.Id;//setting OwnerId
System.assertEquals(null, newtestOpp1.Op_Owner__c, 'The opp owner should be null');
try{        
    insert newtestOpp1;
} catch ( DMLException d ) {
    System.debug(d);
}
System.assertNotEquals(null, newtestOpp1.Op_Owner__c, 'The opp owner should not be null');
```